# Does Spinnaker have fan-in capability?

Tags: spinnaker, go-cd

Does Spinnaker provide "fan in" functionality, like GoCD?  It looks like I can set a single pipeline to trigger multiple downstream pipelines (fan-out), but I can't make a downstream pipeline dependent on the successful completion of two upstream pipelines.  If I set two triggers on the downstream pipeline, it starts immediately following the completion of the first trigger.  I'd like to AND these triggers - ie: when TRIGGER1 and TRIGGER2 complete, start the pipeline.

The image below describes what I'm looking for, visualized in GoCD.  The DeployTest pipeline requires successful completion of ManualGate1 and 2 before it starts.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes - you can do "fan in" operations pretty easily with Spinnaker pipelines.

Select the "DeployTest" stage, then set its "Depends On" stages to include "Manual Gate 1" and "Manual Gate 2":

[image]